# Drupal: Content Type templates

Tags: drupal

It is possible to choose different templates when I am creating a new node?

For example: When i want to create a node of Content Type Product, i want to choose between 4 different templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two answers:

1) create a CCK field that the user will choose what template to use, (e.g. field_template), and add this snippet in your template.php:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (!empty($vars['field_template'][0]['value'])) {
    array_unshift($vars['template_files'], 'node-' . $vars['field_template'][0]['value']);
  }
}
```

That will then try to use *node-template.tpl.php* as your template file, and will fallback to *node.tpl.php* if it doesn't find it.

2) create a Taxonomy for this content type, and design by the taxonomy (something like the code above, only a little modified).

Comment: I like to think of taxonomy as classification of attributes rather than adding attributes to something. So while your second option may work, the first one uses CCK as an attribute of the node which is more appropriate.

Comment: my thought exactly. however, attaching a taxonomy is rather easy for beginners, and CCK is more complex.